Prove that $p = 1/2$ maximizes the entropy of a binomial distribution.
I am trying to find a proof that the entropy of a Binomial distribution is maximized at $p = 1/2$. By symmetry, I can easily show that $p = 1/2$ is a local optimum, but I'm stuck trying to show that $p = 1/2$ is also a global maximum.
The binomial probability distribution is
$$B(n, p, k) = p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
and its entropy is
$$H(n, p) = -\sum_{k=0}^n B(n, p, k) \log B(n, p, k)$$
Is there a known method or theorem that might help?
Any insights or pointers to relevant results would be greatly appreciated!

Hint: use your item 3.

and that if there is a global maximum at $\hat p$ then there is a  global maximum at $1-\hat p$

It seems that the curve $$\mathcal{C}={\text{Bin}(n,p):p \in [0,1]}$$ is not a convex subset of the probability simplex $\Delta^n$ for $n \geq 2$. Then how does the above comments apply? I guess a concave function can assume multiple maxima when it is restricted on a non-convex set, so the question seems trickier...

@KurtG. Mind elaborating a bit? I know that entropy is concave over distributions, but how would I use that to show that entropy is concave in $p$?

Did you try to derive H respect of p ?.

@SangchulLee I've done some reading and saw the following striking fact: the negative entropy of a distribution from the exponential family is the convex conjugate of its log partition function. The binomial distribution is a member of the exponential family and has a log-partition function of $-n \log(1-p)$. I would love to see a proof based on these properties.

Step 1. Reduction. In this step, we represent the derivative of the entropy of a binomial distribution in terms of the difference of KL-divergences.
Write $q = 1-p$ and $P_{n,k}(p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k q^{n-k}$. We also write $P_n(p) = \text{Bin}(n, p)$ for simplicity. Then by noting that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\partial P_{n,k}(p)}{\partial p}
= \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \sum_{k=0}^{n} P_{n,k}(p) = 0, $$
we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \operatorname{H}(P_{n}(p))
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\partial P_{n,k}(p)}{\partial p} \log P_{n,k}(p) \\
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{p} - \frac{n-k}{q} \right) P_{n,k}(p) \log P_{n,k}(p) \\
&= - n \sum_{k=0}^{n} [P_{n-1,k-1}(p) - P_{n-1, k}(p)] \log P_{n,k}(p) \\
&= - n \sum_{k=0}^{n} [P_{n-1,n-k}(q)  \log P_{n,n-k}(q) - P_{n-1, k}(p) \log P_{n,k}(p)].
\end{align*}
The last line can be written as the difference between two cross entropies $\operatorname{H}(P_{n-1}(q) \| P_n(q))$ and $\operatorname{H}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p))$ (up to a constant multiple). So by using the identity
$$ \operatorname{H}(P \| Q) = \operatorname{H}(P) + \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P \| Q), $$
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \operatorname{H}(P_{n}(p))
&= n \left[ \operatorname{H}(P_{n-1}(q) \| P_n(q)) - \operatorname{H}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p)) \right] \\
&= n \bigl[ \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(q) \| P_n(q)) - \operatorname{H}(P_{n-1}(q)) \\
&\hspace{2.5em} + \operatorname{H}(P_{n-1}(p)) - \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p)) \bigr] \\
&= n \bigl[ \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(q) \| P_n(q)) - \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p)) \bigr]
\end{align*}
In light of this identity, it suffices to prove:

Claim. The function $p \mapsto \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p))$ is non-decreasing.


Step 2. Proof of Claim. We establish the claim by showing that the Maclaurin expansion of $\operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p))$ with respect to $p$ has non-negative coefficients. (This in fact proves a much stronger property about the divergence, such as the concavity of $p \mapsto \operatorname{H}(P_n(p))$.)
To this end, we begin by referring to the following integral identity
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - x^{k-1}}{\log(1/x)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \log k, \qquad k > 0. $$
To make use of this identity, we first expand the divergence as follows:
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p)) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P_{n-1,k}(p) \log \biggl( \frac{P_{n-1,k}(p)}{P_{n,k}(p)} \biggr) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P_{n-1,k}(p) \log \biggl( \frac{n-k}{nq} \biggr) \\
&= -\log(nq) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P_{n-1,k}(p) \log(n-k).
\end{align*}
Replacing the logarithm in the summation by the integral representation and applying the binomial theorem,
\begin{align*}
&= -\log(nq) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P_{n-1,k}(p) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - x^{n-k-1}}{\log(1/x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\log(nq) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - (p + qx)^{n-1}}{\log(1/x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\log(nq) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - (x + p(1 - x))^{n-1}}{\log(1/x)} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Now applying the binomial theorem again to expand the integrand,
\begin{align*}
&= -\log(nq) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\log(1/x)} \biggl[ 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} p^k x^{n-1-k}(1 - x)^k \biggr] \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\log(nq)
+ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - x^{n-1}}{\log(1/x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
\\
&\qquad - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\log(1/x)} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} p^k x^{n-1-k}(1 - x)^k  \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\log(1 - p)
- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \biggl[ \binom{n}{k} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n-1-k}(1 - x)^k}{\log(1/x)}  \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr]  p^k.
\end{align*}
Now we invoke the identity
$$ -\log(1-z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k} $$
to deduce that

$-\log(1-p) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{p^k}{k}$ for $p \in [0, 1]$, and

$-\log x = -\log(1 - (1-x)) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^k}{k} \geq 1- x$ whenever $x \in [0, 1]$.


Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n-1-k}(1 - x)^k}{\log(1/x)}  \, \mathrm{d}x
&\leq \binom{n}{k} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1-k}(1 - x)^{k-1}  \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \binom{n}{k} \operatorname{B}(k, n-k) = \frac{1}{k},
\end{align*}
where $\operatorname{B}(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the beta function. Therefore it follows that the Maclaurin expansion
$$ \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p)) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k p^k $$
satisfies
$$ a_k = \frac{1}{k} - \biggl[ \binom{n}{k} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n-1-k}(1 - x)^k}{\log(1/x)}  \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr] \mathbf{1}[0 < k < n] \geq 0. $$
Since all the coefficients in the Maclaurin expansion is non-negative, it therefore follows that $p \mapsto \operatorname{D}_\text{KL}(P_{n-1}(p) \| P_n(p))$ is non-decreasing, completing the proof. $\square$

Awesome, thanks for the answer! Let me make sure that I understand everything going on here. The first step, where you show that the derivative of the entropy is a difference of relative entropies is really neat and reads very clearly (except I think you repeated one line in your steps simplifying the derivative). The rest involves solving for the coefficients of the Maclaurin expansion of the relative entropy and showing that they are all positive. I'll want to go through these steps carefully on my own before I accept your response as the answer.

I realized that once you've reduced the problem to showing that the relative entropy is non-increasing in q, we can use that fact that the same Markov process applied to two distributions cannot increase the KL divergence between those distributions. There is a Markov process which increases $q$, which completes the proof. That said, I think your approach is nice. I would love to see another version along the lines of the information-theoretic approach I outlined as well.

@nlupugla, Thank you for pointing out my mistake! Indeed your understanding is correct, and I added a couple of extra lines just in case the intermediate steps are less transparent. As for your second comment, I guess I am not fully following what Markov process you are considering, but I also do hope to see a more information-theoretic approach. :)

A quick googling seems suggesting that Shepp-Olkin theorem is the relevant keyword (which in fact concerns a much stronger property about the entropy of a  generalized binomial distribution, though). The authors say that the proof is based on Schur covexity, so I guess their approach is not entirely information-theoretic.

To be more specific about the Markov process, imagine an ordered chain of states. During every small interval of time $dt$, there is a probability $r dt k$ for the $kth$ to decay to state $k-1$. So $\partial t P_k = r ((k + 1) P_{k + 1} - k P_k)$ If initially, there is probability $1$ to be in state $n$, then the distribution of states after time $t$ will be given by a binomial distribution with $p = e^{- r t}$.

$H(p):=H(n,p)$ is a continuous function that is  symmetric with respect to the vertical line $p=\frac12$, that is, $$H(p)=H(1-p), p\in [0,1].$$ As $H(0)=H(1)=0$ and $H(p)$ is concave on $[0,1]$ (see below for a proof), the maximum of $H(p)$ is attained at $p=\frac12$ by symmetry.

Concavity of $H(p)$
We can write
$$H(p)=- \mathbb E(X)\log p- \left (n-\mathbb E(X)\right )\log (1-p)-\sum_{k=0}^n B(n, p, k) \log \binom{n}{k}\\ = -\log n!+\Big [ -n\,p\log p+ \mathbb E\log X! \Big ]+\Big [-n\,(1-p)\log (1-p) +\mathbb E\log (n-X)! \Big ]$$
where $$X\sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$$ $$n-X\sim \text{Binomial}(n,1-p).$$
Hence, it is enough to show that
$$C(p) = -n\,p\log p+ \mathbb E\log X!$$
is a concave function on $[0,1]$. By direct calculation, it can be shown that
$$C''(p)=-\frac{n}{p}+n(n-1)\,\mathbb E\log \left (1+\frac{1}{1+Y} \right )$$
where $Y\sim \text{Binomial}(n-2,p).$ Using $\log(1+z) \le z$ for $z> -1$ and that $E\left (\frac{1}{1+Y} \right )=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{(n-1)p}$; see [1] for a proof, we have
$$C''(p) \le -\frac{n}{p}+n(n-1)\,\mathbb E \left (\frac{1}{1+Y} \right )=-\frac{n\,(1-p)^{n-1}}{p} <0, $$
which implies that $C(p)$ is a strictly concave function, so does $H(p)$. The proof of the concavity of $C(p)$ is similar to the one given in Theorem 4 of this paper [2].

Thanks! That is a very nice and self-contained proof. Do you think the last few steps could be streamlined by using Jensen's inequality to bound the expectation value term in the second derivative? We just need to show that it's less than $1/((n-1)p)$.

@nlupugla My pleasure! It seems Jensen's inequality cannot work here as $\log \left (1+\frac{1}{1+x} \right )$ is a convex function, and applying it to $\log$ function yields no simpler proof.
